# How to change object column in Data Frame to numeric column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I have Data Frame like below:

[image]

Both column are as type "object". I need to change column "x" bacuse I want to create a box plot using these data. How can I convert column X to numeric ? 
I tried for example: `pd.to_numeric(df1.x)` nevertheless it generates error: `ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,418997646" at position 0`. DO you have other idea how to change type of this column ?

Comment: use `pd.to_numeric`: `df1['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['x'])`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have this error after using your code: ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,418997646" at position 0

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df1['x'].str.replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Is that comma (as opposed to a decimal point) intentional (such as from a European database)?  If loading with `pd.read_csv` look into using the `decimal` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Quang:

```
df1['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['x'].str.replace(',', '.'))
```

You need to replace `,` with `.` in your strings before you convert them to numeric since they use comma instead of dot for decimal point.